# Can never using a laptop's battery harm the hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have always used power connection with my laptop.
Recently the hard disk was damaged, the tech replaced it and said, not using the battery can damage the hard disk, is this correct?

Comment: Either something got lost in translation, the so-called tech was raving mad, or the battery physically covers the hard disk.

Comment: @Hennes: Perhaps he meant that if there's sudden power loss you might end up with data loss or worse if the drive was in the middle of a write?

Comment: @Karan that would make no difference as long as the battery was there (which I understand it was). Perhaps the battery was overheating and _that_ harmed the drive?

Comment: @terdon: Ah, I read the post to mean the laptop was running directly from the mains with the battery removed.

Comment: @karan I read it as physical damage to the drive. Which should never happen to a laptop drive, even if you run on the power brick with the battery removed. As to FS corruption due to power failure: That would be the same as on desktops.

Comment: TBH the more I look at the post the more I'm unsure of what precisely happened. Besides what was originally said (there's the real possibility simplified language was used), there's also the question of how it was interpreted by a non tech-savvy user and further reported here. Did the guy actually use the word "damage"? If yes, in what sense? Bad sectors that warranted a drive replacement? The answers are valid but in the end we're just guessing/assuming stuff, so I'm gonna VTC for being too ambiguous and NARQ. If further details are provided then the question can be looked at once more.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that he said never using the battery will damage the battery? Because that's actually true; the best way to preserve the running life of modern lithium-ion batteries is not to keep them charged up all the time, but rather to discharge them almost completely and then recharge them to full in one go (i.e., without unplugging at half full and running it down again from there, &c.)

Comment: Never using a battery, or never running off the battery. Never using it to me means removing the battery and running of AC instead...

Comment: To my mind, "using the battery" means powering the laptop from it. Whether you're not doing that because it's plugged in all the time, or because it's not physically in the laptop, seems of secondary import, though the battery will probably keep its charge capacity better in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely nonsense. You cannot damage your hard drive not running on batteries. End of story.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming he meant physical damage, then its utter nonsense. What about the millions, perhaps billions of desktops and servers that run without a battery? The technology from the board to the drives are same.

The data could be damaged, not written properly, or lost. That does not warrant a new hard drive though.

The only circumstance I can come to would be brown=out conditions or spikes where the hardware is constantly going over or under current. This can harm not only the hard drive, but the entire desktop, laptop, or server. Which is part of the reason you use a surge protector or UPS whenever possible for all electronics. If you are behind one of these devices than battery or not makes no difference as far as physical damage.

---

An update, after some more digging [I found this](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/Safe-to-run-Laptop-without-Battery-installed/td-p/21618)

It seems the sales channels teach "Leave the battery in at all times" possibly to help sell more batteries in the long run. But the tech manuals go more this direction:

> "Do not keep a notebook plugged in with its batteries in place at all times. This will cause the battery to lose its calibration and ability to charge correctly."

Answer (score -1):

Despite what everyone else here said (and I first thought) He might be technically correct.

Assuming its a hardware fault -

The battery can act as a power regulator, and thus help protect the hard drive, particularly if the power is unstable.    In reality though, a hard drive should not be affected by the absence of a battery, and hard drives are expected to fail at some point as they have moving parts.

A systems power supply SHOULD regulate well enough to ensure a hard drive is never damaged.

In other words, while it may be correct for a tech to say "its not best practice" to run a laptop without a battery, it is incorrect to blame damage on the lack of a battery.

Assuming its a software fault -

Yes, the tech is correct - if the drive is writing and the power is disconnected it can cause file system problems, which can be described as damage.   (There are filesystems that try very hard to prevent this problem [journaling file systems], so it is a real threat.)

Comment: I am not buying this (No offense). 1) File System corruption is not physical damage, so that's a different point and not a warrantied FRU that the tech should be concerned about. http://superuser.com/questions/233315/is-it-safe-to-operate-a-laptop-without-battery  Again here http://superuser.com/questions/411304/removing-battery-and-running-the-laptop-in-pluged-in-mode Most damning, http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/Safe-to-run-Laptop-without-Battery-installed/td-p/21618 Where the HP sales guy says leave it in, opposite of what the manual says...