# Kernel panic and memory corruption when operating laptops without built-in battery

Tags: laptop, memory, battery, kernel-panic

Sorry in advance for the long winded post but I believe some context/backstory is necessary.

I was running an old Asus GL502VM gaming laptop for about 7 years with Windows 10, plugged in all the time as a sort of desktop PC. The battery failed (partially, puffed up with one cell down) for the second time a few weeks ago and rather than replacing it with yet another one I decided to operate it without any battery.
I wasn't gaming but a few weeks in, I received a BSOD with Windows complaining about memory fault. Ran the Windows Memory Diagnostic tool on reboot and the memory had lots of failed addresses.

It's important to note that this laptop had 8GB soldered-in memory when purchased and I had added an 8GB stick to a free slot immediately thereafter. I had completely forgotten about the former and decided the stick that I could see when opening the back panel had gone bad. It took a few days for a newly purchased 16GB stick to arrive and after some general servicing (dusting, cleaning, new thermal paste), adding the new stick and running the memory diagnostics still produced memory errors. It was at this point I removed the new stick, ran the diagnostics with just the soldered-in RAM and was disappointed to find the errors again.

Decided to get a new laptop thinking the soldered-in RAM had gone bad, this time a modest non-gaming Lenovo V15 G2. Removed the pre-installed Windows 11 and installed LMDE 5 (Linux Mint Debian Edition). As I was using this as a desktop most of the time and remembering the past battery failures I decided to disconnect the battery and use the provided SMPS power supply. A few days later, this laptop also suffered from frequent kernel panics when using even a bit of GPU such as viewing Youtube or logging into a DE in virt-manager. Ran memtest86 and it found memory corruption on the new laptop. After a few mini heart attacks and questioning my existence, finally fixed it by long-pressing the power button to fully discharge the device and re-installing the battery. Ran memtest again without any errors and no more kernel panics.

Decided to check on the old laptop again, this time making sure to long press the power button and ran memtest, there were no errors!

I need some help finding the root cause of the issue:

1. As per [this](https://superuser.com/a/233356/340428) SuperUser answer, it could be due to the stock power adapter not providing adequate power on its own. What is the best way to measure power draw? I have a WiFi-enabled smart socket but not sure if it can record momentary spikes in power draw.
2. I have no *major* reason to doubt the quality of electricity as I have the laptops connected to an APC UPS (normal one, not the fancy double conversion) and a terminal SPD. My only concern is the rather high N-E voltage of 10-20V which is far above the 3V recommended by IEEE, this has not caused any issues AFAICT and I have previously ran a different Xiaomi laptop without built-in battery for a few years without any memory corruption issues.

Comment: I disagree with at least half of the answers on that link. The battery's job is to power the computer. The charger's job is to charge the battery. It cannot cope with the full peak demand of the computer. It's not designed to. Having said that, **some** just manage to get away with it… others, not so much.

Comment: Some laptops are not designed to be used without a battery.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think the battery is involved once it's fully charged. Looks like the Lenovo laptop using BYD battery bypasses the battery altogether when fully charged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue on different laptops (old and new) was caused by multiple problems not related to each other.

1. On old laptop (assumption): due to dust and/or overheating. Fixed after cleaning and discharging the device completely.

**Update on Oct 6 2023**

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue with my old laptop, but it's interesting to note that at the time of the issue I was operating it with the backplate open (for better cooling) and I was sitting right underneath a long aircon power line which could've caused EMI interference. I have been dealing with similar EMI problems happening in another room where the power line and audio-video cables are routed on the opposite sides of the room (narrow width) but still caused the HDMI video to cut out during an aircon cold start.

2. On new laptop (confirmed): using mismatched memory modules caused the integrated GPU which shares system RAM to glitch. No issues reported by memtest86 with the mismatched modules as it tests only CPU and RAM. Fixed after changing out the addon module/stick to match the soldered-in one.

**Regarding power consumption**

As per some rough power consumption measurements taken using a smart wifi socket, the Lenovo V15 laptop with its default 65W charger/adapter and the built-in battery disconnected does not draw more than 40W under concurrent CPU, GPU, I/O stress testing. Only when the battery is connected and is itself charging and under stress testing does it draw the maximum 65W from the charger. Using the laptop with its built-in battery disconnected poses no issues.